# JSF: make A.jsf a default page to go to when type mydomain.com

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Right now, every time I type `mydomain.com` it would automatically go to `mydomain.com/projectname/home.jsf`, which is my login page. Not sure why, I know I still in session meaning that I can navigate to a restricted page without login in again. So how do I make so that if I type `mydomain.com`, I go to `mydomain.com/projectname/CentralFeed.jsf` instead of login page if the user still in session. Here is my rough design

In my web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>CentralFeed.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>          
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc-realm-scholar</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/home.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/LoginError.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.scholar.servlet.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/CentralFeed.jsf</url-pattern>        
    <url-pattern>/TextBook.jsf</url-pattern>
    ...
</filter-mapping>
```

I am not sure if you guys need to know this, but I also have a Filter call `MyFilter`, which map to restricted page, and check if the user still in session, if so then just `chain.doFilter(req, res);`, if not then redirect to login page `home.jsf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put `index.jsp`

and in it put

```
<% response.sendRedirect("desired URL"); %>
```

remove

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>CentralFeed.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

from `web.xml`

Comment: yes. by `response.sendRedirect()` you will just make client to `GET` desired `URL` which you want to redirect from root

Comment: I hope you dont mind if I ask this, so CentralFeed.jsf is the page I want to always go first. If I change that page to index.jsf, will I get the same result, like what you suggest above?

Comment: Dont think it work: Here is my Exception: `javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 12] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.` I am using JSF Facelets btw

Comment: nvm, it has to be a .jsp file instead of .xhtml

Answer (score 4):

The `<welcome-file>` has to point to a physical file on the disk, not to some servlet mapping. Since you've a `CentralFeed.xhtml` file, a `<welcome-file>` of `CentralFeed.jsf` isn't going to work.

There are two solutions (apart from the *scriptlet* hack as suggested by Jigar):

1. Create an empty file `CentralFeed.jsf` file next to the `CentralFeed.xhtml`. This fools the server that the file is physically present.
2. Map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` instead of `*.jsf`. While this was impossible in JSF 1.x because it would run in an infinite loop, this works fine on JSF 2.0. Your question history confirms that you're using JSF 2.0. This way you can just set the `<welcome-file>` to `CentralFeed.xhtml`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great information. Learn something new :D