# Redirection from root (index.html) on JSF RichFaces

Tags: jsf, redirect, navigation, richfaces

Trying to redirect to `admin.xhtml` page when I access `http://localhost:8080/CSPPortal/index.html`. The root `index.html` contains

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=pages/admin.jsf"/></head></html>
```

The **problem** is the **url keeps going back** to `login.jsf` which was declared in the `index.html` before.

**Tried:** adding an empty `index.jsf` page to the root folder. Tried mapping `FacesServelet` on `*.xhtml` [old answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5345633/1108500). Tried removing `<welcome-file-list>` from `web.xml`. **ALL trial FAILED!!!!** Any suggestion about where things are going wrong would be really appreciated.

Here is `web.xml` content:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Navigation rule in `faces-config.xml` is as follows, because I don't have any link for admin.xhtml yet:

```
<navigation-rule>
 <from-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
 <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>result</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/pages/result.xhtml</to-view-id>
 </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Using, JBoss AS 7.1, RichFaces 4.0, JSF 2.0 (via JBoss Tools)

Answer (score 2):

Since the URL is invoked by the browser, you need to resolve the url like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=#{request.contextPath}/pages/admin.jsf"/>
```

See also:

- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url)

Comment: your suggestion works when the problem is the path. But this is something different. RichFaces x.x need to have an index.jsf file to process, which can be just created and left empty. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection from root (index.html) on JSF RichFaces

1.Put in xhtml file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=index.jsf">
  </head>
</html>
```

2.Web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The externalContext approach works fine for me.

```
<h:body>
  #{facesContext.externalContext.response.sendRedirect('pages/admin.jsf')}
</h:body>
```